# Variance and expected value of continuous random variable, with density $1/3$ and $1/6$, why 0?

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, continuity, random-variables

I'm working with this

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/3 & 0 < |x| < 1 \\
1/6 & 1 < x < 2 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

This is my procedure

$$\int_{0}^1 1/3x dx + \int_1^2 {1/6x}dx = 
 1/6 + 1/4= 5/12$$

The book says that the expected value is 0.

Comment: The first statement can actually be translated into $1/3\ \text{when} -1 < x < 1$ so you miss an integral.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac 13$ when $|x| < 1 \implies  f(x) = \frac 13$ when  $-1<x<1$

Comment: why another integral? are you splitting the first statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably lost absolute value bars on the $x$ in $1 \lt x \lt 2$, or maybe it is a typo in the book.  Putting them on lets the function integrate to $1$ as it should for a probability distribution.  It also makes the function symmetric around zero, so the expected value will integrate to zero.  You would need two more integrals, one from $-2$ to $-1$ and one from $-1$ to $0$ to compute this and will duly get zero.

Comment: maybe it's a typo. But why 1?

Comment: A probability distribution has to integrate to $1$ because it is certain that the random variable has some value

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have absolute value so the first integral should be from $-1$ to $1$. But actually that density functiom doesn't even integrate to 1 so I think there is an error.